# form action from phtml to controller

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am developing website in which i have signup newsletter in my home page.

I don't want to use default newsletter feature available in magento. But i want implement it this because of some other customizations i want. But i am not sure how i can call the controller(to make entry in database and give response)  when signup/submit pressed.

**Questions**
How can i do this?
Is there any other preferable way to implement signup feature manually ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below your it is very help full to you.

Custom Module with Custom Database Table

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

you can take help from above link and make your own front end custom form and module

Comment: inserted values from controller to database. but still don't know how to call controller's action from phtml file.

Comment: @BSThakrar, pls check your form post action. i would be glad if voteup and acpt my answer so some one can use it in future reference.

Comment: can i call any controller's method from main index file ?

Comment: i am not getting. what u are trying to say. will pls give one example. ?

Comment: we have default installation index.php file i want to call method from local/Company/helloworld/help method. can i do it?